# output http request node.js in aws lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {

  // TODO implement
  const https = require('https');
  https.get('https://postman-echo.com/get?' +
    'username =' +
    '&password =' +
    '&date=' +
    '&cashSales=' + +
    '&creditCardVisa=' +
    '&creditCardMaster=' + +
    '&creditCardAmex=' +
    '&creditCardOthers=0',
    res => {
      //console.log(res.statusCode);
      //console.log(res.headers);

      let body = '';

      res.on('data', data => {
        body += data;
      })

      res.on('end', () => console.log(body));

    })

  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(https.get),
  };
  return response;
};
```

I can't seem to output the http request using this function, this can run in node.js but not in aws lambda, even after putting it in response function.

Answer (score 0):

I have restructed the code a bit and wrapped it in a promise. You were not returning anything from the function. see here

```
const https = require("https");

exports.handler = event => {
  return Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    https.get(
      "https://postman-echo.com/get?" +
        "username =" +
        "&password =" +
        "&date=" +
        "&cashSales=" +
        +"&creditCardVisa=" +
        "&creditCardMaster=" +
        +"&creditCardAmex=" +
        "&creditCardOthers=0",
      resp => {
        let data = "";

        // A chunk of data has been recieved.
        resp.on("data", chunk => {
          data += chunk;
        });

        // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
        resp.on("end", () => {
          resolve(data);
        });

        resp.on("error", error => {
          reject(error);
        });
      }
    );
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you were close. But I found two issues.

- Your lambda function was not waiting for the http get to finish.
- You were returning the incorrect value `https.get`. you should return the response payload of the `https.get` call.

I have fixed the issues above.

```
const https = require("https");

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const httpResponse = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    https.get(
      "https://postman-echo.com/get?" +
      "username =" +
      "&password =" +
      "&date=" +
      "&cashSales=" +
      +"&creditCardVisa=" +
      "&creditCardMaster=" +
      +"&creditCardAmex=" +
      "&creditCardOthers=0",
      resp => {
        let body = '';

        // A chunk of data has been recieved.
        resp.on("data", chunk => {
          body += chunk;
        });

        // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
        resp.on("end", () => {
          resolve(body);
        });

        resp.on("error", error => {
          reject(error);
        });
      }
    );
  });

  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(httpResponse),
  };
  return response;
};
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think others have already pointed out the problem in your code. You are not waiting for the http get call to complete before returning. Read [this article](https://sarthakj178.com/handling-nodejs-promises-in-aws-lambda/) which explains the incorrect handling of Promises in AWS Lambda functions and the solutions for that.

If you use [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) library (a much more popular one on npm) instead of https and with the new [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await) syntax, your code will become very simple.

```
exports.handler = async function(event) {
    const request = require('request-promise');
    const res = await request.get('https://postman-echo.com/get', {
        params: {
            username: '',
            password: '',
            date: '',
            cashSales: '',
            creditCardVisa: '',
            creditCardMaster: '',
            creditCardAmex: '',
            creditCardOthers: '0'
        }
    });
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(res)
    };
    return response;
};
```