# How to get mysql data in httpget request in node.js lambda aws

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

```
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {

var yesterday = new Date(Date.now() - 864e5);
var dd = yesterday.getDate();
var mm = yesterday.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = yesterday.getFullYear();

// Use the connection
connection.query("SELECT id, restaurant_id, revenue_id, revenue_name, total_cash,visa,mc,amex, 
DATE_FORMAT(business_date, '%d-%M-%Y') as business_date, item_sales FROM `alfred- 
prod`.report_day_sales where restaurant_id=19  and DATE_FORMAT(business_date, '%Y-%m-%d') = 
DATE_FORMAT('2014-09-01', '%Y-%m-%d')", function (error, results, fields) {
console.log("SELECT id, restaurant_id, revenue_id, revenue_name, total_cash,visa,mc,amex, 
DATE_FORMAT(business_date, '%d-%M-%Y') as business_date, item_sales FROM `alfred- 
prod`.report_day_sales where restaurant_id=230  and DATE_FORMAT(business_date, '%Y-%m-%d') = 
DATE_FORMAT('"+yyyy+"-"+mm+"-"+dd+"', '%Y-%m-%d')")})



});

 const response = {


statusCode: 200,



body: JSON.stringify(

    https.get('https://postman-echo.com/get?'+ 
           'username ='+ 
           '&password ='+
           '&date=' + results[0].business_date + 
           '&cashSales='+ results[0].total_cash +
           '&creditCardVisa='+ results[0].visa +
           '&creditCardMaster='+ results[0].mc +
           '&creditCardAmex=' + results[0].amex +
           '&creditCardOthers=0',

    res => {
//console.log(res.statusCode);
//console.log(res.headers);

let body = '';

res.on('data',data =>{
    body += data;
  })

  res.on('end',()=>console.log(body));

 })




    ),
};
  return response;
};
```

I'm trying to get a response from the http request, with results[0].business date, results[0].total_cash and everything else. But I get an error instead of an output. This is the error -

Response:
{
  "errorType": "ReferenceError",
  "errorMessage": "results is not defined",
  "trace": [
    "ReferenceError: results is not defined",
    "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:45:27)",
    "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
  ]
}

Comment: you have not define the results array of object, from where this result is coming

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do. If i am understanding you correctly, You are trying to query mysql to get the results and using that result to send an http request.

```
const https = require("https");

const getResults = () => {
  const queryResponse = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {

      var yesterday = new Date(Date.now() - 864e5);
      var dd = yesterday.getDate();
      var mm = yesterday.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
      var yyyy = yesterday.getFullYear();

      const query = "SELECT id, restaurant_id, revenue_id, revenue_name, total_cash,visa,mc,amex, DATE_FORMAT(business_date, '%d-%M-%Y') as business_date, item_sales FROM `alfred-\
      prod`.report_day_sales where restaurant_id = 19  and DATE_FORMAT(business_date, '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT('2014-09-01', '%Y-%m-%d')"
      // Use the connection
      connection.query(query, (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
        }

        resolve(results)
      })
    });
  });

  return queryResponse;
}

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const httpResponse = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const results = await getResults();

    const { business_date, total_cash, visa, mc, amex } = results[0]
    https.get(
      `https://postman-echo.com/get?username=&password=&date=${business_date}&cashSales=${total_cash}&creditCardVisa=${visa}&creditCardMaster=${mc}&creditCardAmex=${amex}&creditCardOthers=0`,
      resp => {
        let body = '';

        // A chunk of data has been recieved.
        resp.on("data", chunk => {
          body += chunk;
        });

        // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
        resp.on("end", () => {
          resolve(body);
        });

        resp.on("error", error => {
          reject(error);
        });
      }
    );
  });

  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(httpResponse),
  };
  return response;
};
```

Note: I haven't tested this code, Also this is not a complete code.

Comment: answered a similar question yesterday:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59518609/output-http-request-node-js-in-aws-lambda/59519949#59519949